# Why is SHA1 hashing the same string differently?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sha1

This is the code I have to salt and hash a user's password when they register (with the actual password hashing taken out because it was hashing consistently). What is happening is that when I use the first block of code, if I try and hash the salt I find in the database after a user registers, it hashes to something different than what gets stored in password_digest. However, if I use the second or third blocks of code, they hash to the same thing, which is the behavior I want.

```
salt = rand
write_attribute :password_digest, Digest::SHA1.hexdigest("#{salt}")
write_attribute :salt, salt
```

vs.

```
salt = "#{rand}"
write_attribute :password_digest, Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(salt)
write_attribute :salt, salt
```

[EDIT]

or

```
salt = rand
write_attribute :password_digest, Digest::SHA1.hexdigest("#{salt}")
write_attribute :salt, "{#salt}"
```

Both `salt` and `password_digest` are of type `:string`.

[end EDIT]

Why is this? It seems to me that they should have exactly the same behavior. If I store `"#{salt}"` directly in password_digest without hashing it, it matches the `salt` attribute exactly, so it seems that they should hash to the same thing regardless of when the hashing happens. Furthermore, if I manually create a user in the database which involves calling this same function to set the password, the hashes match properly regardless of which block of code I am using, so the hash conflict only seems to occur when I create a user through the browser form.

[EDIT] The third block of code seems to indicate that calling write_attribute on salt without explicitly coercing (is this the right term?) it to a string changes the value of the salt somehow when it gets stored in the database... Though this seems unlikely to me.

[EDIT] To give an example of the first block of code's behavior:
In the database,

`password_digest = "2f4d39ae81f480f6ad8a759eec6b8b386fbdf636"` and

`salt = 0.17127103546001`.

However, `Digest::SHA1.hexdigest("0.17127103546001") = "c46566206c072dd453220dac835de6204e64c044"`.

Comment: Could you post your definitions of `:salt` and `:password_digest` properties? They may be relevant, so might be any validation or coercion performed on the salt (as in the first piece of code you are setting it as a float and expecting it to coerce to a string).

Comment: could you post the values so we can try it out, too?

Comment: Edited above - :salt and :password_digest are both strings. Also added an example of what happens with the first block of code.